# Wordpress: How to compare 2 float values in meta_value column?

Tags: wordpress, floating-point

I have about 100 posts in wordpress, all with a meta_key of price and a value.

How would I go about searching through all posts with a value between 23.00 and 41.00 for example?

I know that 'meta_compare ' treats 'meta_value' as a string, so I can't use this to solve my problem. Anybody have any clues? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try to implement the `posts_where` filter, and modify the query there. It gets called right after the meta comparison is added, and it allows you to change the `WHERE` part of your query. You need to replace all instances of your meta key to `CAST(meta_key AS DECIMAL(5,2))`. I guess the meta key is prefixed by the meta table name, so check for that. You will need to figure out a way to pass two `meta_value` parameters if you want to do a `BETWEEN` query, but you can combine them with a comma and split them up in your filter. As long as a valid SQL where-clause comes out of you filter, everything should work.